# Obfuscate password in url

Tags: python, logging, obfuscation, urlparse

I want to obscure a password in a URL for logging purposes. I was hoping to use [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html), by parsing, replacing password with dummy password, and unparsing, but this is giving me:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> parts = urlparse('https://user:pass@66.66.66.66/aaa/bbb')
>>> parts.password = 'xxx'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

So the alternative seems to be [this](https://www.metabrite.com/devblog/posts/python-obfuscate-url-password/), which seems overkill.

Is there an easier way of replacing the password, using the standard library?

Comment: What is `parts` here?

Comment: @AKS: sorry, I thought it was clear. Added more context.

Comment: @janbrohl: That is exactly what the linked script is doing, and it seems overkill to me just because urlparse does not allow to set the separate components.

Comment: I think one of the best way is to write a logger handler which will obfuscate password during logs creation

Comment: For a simpler solution can't you directly replace the string by getting anything like this `:pass@` and replacing it?

Comment: don't forget to pad (or intersperse) your password with junk characters, so the attacker won't know the password's length.

Comment: @AKS: do not want to do custom implementation in order to avoid bugs for corner cases.

Comment: Deleted my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`urlparse` returns a (subclass of) *named tuple*. Use the [`namedtuple._replace()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace) to produce a new copy, and use `geturl()` on that to 'unparse'.

The password is part of the `netloc` attribute, which can be parsed further:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def replace_password(url):
    parts = urlparse(url)
    if parts.password is not None:
        # split out the host portion manually. We could use
        # parts.hostname and parts.port, but then you'd have to check
        # if either part is None. The hostname would also be lowercased.
        host_info = parts.netloc.rpartition('@')[-1]
        parts = parts._replace(netloc='{}:xxx@{}'.format(
            parts.username, host_info))
        url = parts.geturl()
    return url
```

Demo:

```
>>> replace_password('https://user:pass@66.66.66.66/aaa/bbb')
'https://user:xxx@66.66.66.66/aaa/bbb'
```

Comment: That is genious! Let me test it.

Comment: @delavnog: slight issue: there is no password field; i'll update with the right field.

Comment: Why not just checking if `parts.password is not None`?

Comment: @warvariuc: because I forgot about that attribute ;-)

Comment: Ok, that is a good middleground: some custom parsing there, but seems harmless enough. Not so good as the original replace password idea, but I guess urlparse / urlunparse does not allow for that. Thanks!